# Questions about Economics as a discipline

Tags: discussion, topicality

Would the main or the meta be an appropriate place to ask about publishing protocol?

(Journals to submit to, procedure, costs, policies, etc)

This isn't necessarily specific to Economics, but would presumably be relevant to the profession.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Meta is never appropriate for any question that is not about the administration of a normal SE site. I don't think that publishing fits into the main site itself, that would rather be academia.se

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Foobar that Meta should not be used for purposes other than discussing the administration of the site. Questions about publications that are specific to economics should be fine on main, but for more general questions there is [academia.SE](http://academia.stackexchange.com).

The publication process in economics is quite idiosyncratic, so I can see a pretty good case for a lot of these kinds of questions making it onto Econ.SE.

Comment: agreed about the publication process in econ being idiosyncratic. I think that is a good justification for allowing such questions on econ.se (they often wouldn't get relevant answers from academics in general). There is also the pragmatic justification that discussion about publications will attract academics - as opposed to amateurs - which is an important goal.

Comment: The sort of questions that are identified in the question, such as what journal to submit to, would typically get promptly closed and deleted on Academia.SE.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers So do you think they should be allowed here or not? What makes this site different for an opinion based advice question like that?

Comment: I didn't necessarily mean what journal to publish to based on opinion of quality, but more on specific niche publications, or policies related to multiple submission... i.e. If I submit to XYZ, how long would I have to wait to submit to ABC? Can I submit a paper to PQR and Arxiv?